# How to remove duplicate content in end of url?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove a duplicate bar `/` that is at the end of the URL?

My URL input: `https://myurl.com///` 
My output must be like this: `https://myurl.com`

I tried something like this (but without success):

```
let url = "https://myurl.com//"

function remove(url){
    while(url.substr(url.length - 1) === "/"){
        url.slice(0, -1)    
    }   
    return url
}
```

How can I do this? Someone can help me?

Comment: Your code works if you add `url = url.slice(0, -1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with regex. This will remove all `/` from the end of the string

```js
const pattern = /\/+$/;

var url = 'https://myurl.com///';

console.log(url.replace(pattern, ''));
```